# Sum values in a Python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to sum the values in a python dict when I add the same key?

```
d = {'key1':10,'key2':14,'key3':47}
d['key1'] = 20
```

After the above the value of `d['key1']` should be 30.

Is this possible?

Comment: Make a dict-like class with a `__setitem__()` that does this.

Comment: this is not exactly what you want, but it might help you:  d['key1'] = d.get('key1', 0) + 20

Comment: _"How to __sum__ in Python dict when I __add__ the same key?"_ - This is not intuitive. This is not the Python way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d =Counter()
>>> d.update({'key1':10,'key2':14,'key3':47})
>>> d['key1'] += 20
>>> d['key4'] += 50  # Also works for keys that are not present
>>> d
Counter({'key4': 50, 'key3': 47, 'key1': 30, 'key2': 14})
```

Counter has some advantages:

```
>>> d1 = Counter({'key4': 50, 'key3': 4})
#You can add two counters
>>> d.update(d1)
>>> d
Counter({'key4': 100, 'key3': 51, 'key1': 30, 'key2': 14})
```

You can get a list of sorted items(based on the value) using `most_common()`:

```
>>> d.most_common()
[('key4', 100), ('key3', 51), ('key1', 30), ('key2', 14)]
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> keys = [ random.randint(0,1000) for _ in xrange(10**4)]
>>> def dd():                             
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for k in keys:
        d[k] += 10
...         
>>> def count():                             
    d = Counter()
    for k in keys:
        d[k] += 10
...         
>>> def simple_dict():
...     d = {}
...     for k in keys:
...         d[k] = d.get(k,0) + 10
...         
>>> %timeit dd()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.47 ms per loop
>>> %timeit count()
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
>>> %timeit simple_dict()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: Both methods (Counter,defaultdict) do what I want. In that case, which is faster?

Comment: @user7172 I've added some timing comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
d['key1'] += 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   dict[key1]+=20 #The value you wanted
except KeyError:
   dict[key1]=10 #The initial Value
```

Answer (score 0):

d = {'key1':10,'key2':14,'key3':47}

**Solution in One line to sum the values in a python dict when we add the same key:**

d['key1'] = dict.get('key1', 0) + 20

**Explanation:**

dict.get('key1', 0)

this will return the the key value if found in dict otherwise return default value as 0